# Can't remove exif data with Node: seeing exif data written into the buffer in two different formats

Tags: node.js, image, bitmap, exif, arraybuffer

Here’s what I’m trying to do:

1. Download a tiny placeholder image `axios.get(imgUrl, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })`.
2. Remove exif data (ICC profile). This is the tricky bit.
3. BASE64 encode it `Buffer.from(img.data, 'binary').toString('base64')`.
4. Cache for later use.

Some images have an Adobe ICC profile attached to them which adds significantly to the size, and thus I’d like to remove it before encoding.

I’m able to work with the exif data on the [original image](https://images.ctfassets.net/q33z48p65a6w/1G1xXZkbjQKwJeA8LnzZiG/7602e2717304093971471e5621d8b1b0/Tool_List.jpg). But if I use [query params on the URL](https://images.ctfassets.net/q33z48p65a6w/1G1xXZkbjQKwJeA8LnzZiG/7602e2717304093971471e5621d8b1b0/Tool_List.jpg?w=20) to change its size `?w=20` I can’t access the Exif data anymore, I’m just reminded that there is no exif data. I use [node-exif](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif). The exif data clearly is there still, since the created BASE64 string is as large as before.

If I look into the buffers `Buffer.from(img.data, "binary").toString("utf8", 0, 370)` I see they look very different. This is the original image which I can read the exif from:

```
����;ExifMMb(1!r2��i��-��'-��'Adobe Photoshop 21.1 (Macintosh)2020:03:25 10:35:31������"HH����
                 Adobe_CM��Adobed����
```

Here's the resized image that claims to contain no exif data:

```
����JFIF,,��`ICC_PROFILEPapplmntrRGB XYZ �
                                                acspAPPLAPPL���-appldescPbdscm�6cprt�#wtptrXYZ$gXYZ8bXYZLrTRC`
                          aargl vcgt�0ndin�>chad�,mmod((bTRC`
                                                            gTRC`
                                                                aabgl aaggl
```

What do you think is happening when the image is resized?

Here's a demo of the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-sea-68eny?file=/src/index.js